# How do I troubleshoot entire house power outage that immediately comes back on?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel, circuit-breaker

In the last nine-months, the power at my house entirely goes out, then comes back on a fairly unpredictable basis (i.e. not correlated to anything turning on /off).

The breaker box looks fine.

Could a fault in the house be tripping the entire house? Or is it external to the house and maybe a power outage in the system?

Comment: I would imagine it is more the power company than the house.  I get power outages lasting a second to hours.  I would try to keep track of them, date/time and contact the power company, they should have any reports about outages.

Comment: Thanks. I do work to replace electrical sockets / light switches with IoT devices -  my understanding is the breakerbox is the control to prevent contagion from a mistake / issue at the endpoint...

Comment: Ask your neighbors if they are having outages at the same time. At times in the past we had momentary outages (100 ms or 0,1 s) which caused us more trouble than longer outages. Our a/c condensing unit could not handle these brief outages. If the scroll compressor was running at the time of the momentary interruption, it would reverse direction, continue running backwards under power until the compressor overheated and tripped the internal thermal overload switch. Our new unit handles these much better. The compressor made a different sound when running backwards, and the unit does not cool.

Comment: Particularly if you have overhead line type service, cast a critical eye at it (while maintaining a safe distance, of course.) The lines can wear away insulation and have issues in the wind, for instance. Greg Hill's answer is good. While going outside to check the meter, keep an eye out for visible or audible sparks from the supply lines as well. If you notice any, call the power company and report them.

Comment: Similar to what @Ecnerwal said, we used to get momentary power cuts in storms despite our feed being underground. It turned out to be arcing on the high voltage lines supplying the area, so everything in sight flickered at least.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Electrical faults in homes (and buildings generally) do not auto-reset. If a circuit breaker trips, or a fuse blows, or a GFCI interrupts the power, the power remains interrupted until somebody actively resets things.

If power goes out in the entire house, and especially if it restores without any intervention, it's caused either by an outage from the power supplier or by a wiring fault (a loose connection).

The electric meters in many places have been updated to models that have an LCD screen. Go have a look at yours - watch it for 10-20 seconds to become a little familiar with what "normal" looks like. The next time you notice power is out in the entire house, hurry out to look at the electric meter. Electric meters usually do not run on battery. If the LCD screen is acting in the normal way then utility power is almost certainly present at the meter. If the screen is blank, though, this is a good indicator that the power company is having an outage. During night hours, looking to the neighbors' houses for lights also is a telling sign.

You can use the observation of the electric meter to figure out your next steps: if the utility power stays on while you have an outage then an electrician could help you figure out what's wrong with your house. If it's a utility outage, then report it to the utility operator in case *they* have a wiring fault they don't know about.

Comment: A tip on neighbor's lights - it turns out the street in front of my house separates two different substation feeds. So my neighbor across from me can have power when I don't. I learned to look out my back window to the neighbor there and see if their lights are out also...

Answer (score 4):

In the US, the power grid is equipped with "[automatic reclosers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recloser)". These are, essentially circuit breakers that are designed to trip when there's a short, then automatically close themselves. They do this because usually the short is caused by a very short-term, transitory action, like a wet branch falling off a tree, contacting two wires (shorting them), then continuing its fall to the ground.

Usually, the reclosers will try 3 times before remaining tripped.

If this is local to *your* house only, then you're lucky that you've got a recloser on the pole feeding your property. If it's local to the block/neighborhood, then there's one a little further upstream that feeds the whole area.

If this happens frequently, you may want to look at *when* it's happening (during rain storms? During thunder storms? During wind storms? At random times when there isn't any adverse weather?) If there doesn't seem to be a weather related cause, and/or there are trees in close proximity to your power lines, you might give the PoCo a call and talk to them about it. You might be able to get them to come cut back trees that are too close, or take a look at the cable placement on the poles. If there's too much slack or they're too close, they could be contacting each other in strong winds. That would be the PoCo's responsibility to fix.

All in all, be happy that the power blinks out - it's protecting your house from a potentially damaging surge, and be extra happy that it comes right back on. If it didn't you'd have to call the PoCo each time and wait for them to roll a truck to close the breaker for you.

If the power drops are causing havoc with TVs, computers, other high tech devices, then it's time to start investing in device level or a whole house level uninterruptible power supply (UPS).

Comment: I always wondering why a 30-60 second outage would occur. "Automatic reclosers" explain it.

Answer (score 3):

If this is happening regularly, IE more than a few times a year, your first line of action is to call the power company *every single time* it happens.  The problem is probably theirs and is probably hard to pin down.   Your complaints, and perhaps those of any neighbors, are important data points for them.

Second, if you are inclined to do their work for them and if your power comes from a pole, is to follow (visually) the wire from your house to the transformer that feeds it and see which other houses are fed by the same transformer.  Usually 2 to 5 others.  Go ask THOSE neighbors if they have the same problems and ask THEM to report them every time too.  It may not be your next door neighbors, they may be behind you or across the road or a few houses away.

VERY unlikely to be your issue but the only things in your domain that would take out your whole house and recover would be a loose connection on your side of the meter or at the main lug in your breaker panel.  That should be easy for a professional electrician to triage.

Answer (score 0):

You say the power goes completely out, and then comes back sometime later, after some period of time, and that time varies.

It's doubtful it's anything related to your house internal circuits or breaker panel.   But you need to verify if it's just your house experiencing it, or others nearby are also experiencing it.  Definitely call the power company each time the power goes out.  As others have said, check to see if your meter has it's LCD panel on (if you have that type), when your house has lost power.

Assuming it's your power company, you want want to consider a whole house generator.   Some places don't have the most reliable power, and it would definitely help with getting things more stable for your house.   The nice thing is, having a generator will help with the surge that occurs when the power comes back on.  And especially helpful when the power comes back on/goes back out a few times in a row.